# How to configure Jenkins dashboard from the console error?

Tags: jenkins

I am planning to create a Jenkins dashboard by categorizing the jobs based on the build  errors.

I have the groovy script to parse the console error, but I don't see an option to insert into the dashboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the [view job filter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) ?

Comment: Hi, Yes. I did. But it doesn't has an option to filter based on the build errors.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there were no straight forward option to customize the dashboard view.

So I have written my own script and generated the HTML file and I used the HTML Publisher plugin to display as dashboard.

Thank everyone for your help.